# why dest array needs so many space for strcat in c

Tags: c

my code as following:

```
int main(){
  char str[10];
  char test[2]={'a','b'};
  strcat(str,test);
  printf("%s\n",str);
  return 0;
}
```

if I set str[3] instead of str[10] then the program would corrupt.Why str[] needs so many spaces, though I only have 2 letters to copy.

Comment: Neither `str` nor `test` are null-terminated byte strings - your code invokes *undefined behavior*

Comment: two problems. 1) str is uninitialized and thus not null terminated. 2) test is not null terminated

Comment: Also, `test` isn't allocated enough memory to contain a null-termination character.

Comment: You need to understand why `char test[] = "ab"` produces a different sized array than `char test[2]={'a', 'b'}`

Comment: @Ivan: Voting on a question is not a judgement about whether the question violates guidelines or rules, and it is not a judgement about the author. The Stack Overflow guidelines for voting largely involve whether questions are useful or not.

Comment: Ah im aware of that but i still fail to see the reason behind 3 instant downvotes in a fairly average question.

Comment: Maybe because it's a pan-galactic dupe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your program, strcat() first looks at str[10] and scans forward looking for the end-of-string character (NUL/zero). When it finds that, it then copies the string in test[] starting, until it comes to the NUL at the end of that string.

What you want t have is this:

```
str[10] = [NUL,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?]
test[3] = [a,b,NUL]
```

but what you actually have is this:

```
str[10] = [?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,...]
test[2] = [a,b,?,?,?,?,...]
```

Strcat will keep copying until it finds a zero, which could be thousands of bytes past the end of the array. You will either get a seg fault, or overwrite random data. Strcat does not know anything about your array sizes.

The string "ab" requires an array of length [3], because it also includes a NUL character, so your declaration for test is too small.

In C, a quoted string automatically includes the NUL at the end, but an array does not. What you want is something like this:

```
char str[10] = {'\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0'};
char test[3] = {'a','b','\0'};
```

Or, you can write it more simply like this:

```
char str[10] = "";
char test[3] = "ab";
```

Comment: Your first "what you want" declaration of test should be test[3], not test[2]